# Image preview is too stretched

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use a camera to click an image and display it in my fragment. This is my code:

fragment_image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:background="@color/translucent_grey"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_location"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp" >

            <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/snap"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
         android:background="@color/white"
         android:src="@drawable/camera" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="300dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>     

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/datetime_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
<FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/eventDetails_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ImageFragment.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    try {
        cr.notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        File imageFile = new File(tempPhoto.getAbsolutePath());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Bitmap photo=null;
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                photo = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, Uri.fromFile(tempPhoto));
                //image.setImageBitmap(photo);
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo);
                image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                //image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }               
}
```

Despite following the advice on this thread, my image is still stretched as shown:
[image]

Do you know what's the problem with what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to imageview works:

```
android:minHeight="120dp" 
     android:minWidth="180dp" 
     android:maxWidth="420dp" 
     android:maxHeight="680dp" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the scale type `ScaleType.FIT_XY` with `ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE`:

```
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

As described in [Android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

> CENTER_INSIDE     Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: Hi.. I actually want the image to stretch across the width of the screen (just like fb mobile newsfeed). When I do  ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, it makes the image smaller. Is there a way to stretch the width of the image, and adjust the height such that the image scales uniformly

Comment: But your image's height is greater than width, right? It seems to be stretched horizontally.

Comment: I see. So how should I set the height such that an image spreads across the screen width, and the height is set dynamically to maintain the image scale?

Comment: Well you can't in case of a vertical image. If you stretch the width to fill the screen, the height will be longer than the display.

Comment: hey, I actually figured it out. I had to just add minheight and maxheight parameters to the imageview. Thanks for your help!